# NSMutableArray property initialization and updating

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, initialization, nsinteger

Suppose I have a @property that is an NSMutablearray that is to contain scores used by four objects. They will be initialized as zero and then updated during viewDidLoad and throughout operation of the app.

For some reason, I can't wrap my mind around what needs to be done, particularly at the declaration and initialization steps.

I believe this can be a private property.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *scores;

@synthesize scores = _scores;
```

Then in viewDidLoad I try something like this but get an error. I just need help with syntax, I think. Or I'm missing something very basic.

```
self.scores = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@0,@0,@0,@0,nil];
```

Is that an appropriate way to initialize it? Then how do I add (NSNumber *)updateValue to, say, the nth value?

Edit: I think I figured it out.

```
-(void)updateScoreForBase:(int)baseIndex byIncrement:(int)scoreAdjustmentAmount
{
    int previousValue = [[self.scores objectAtIndex:baseIndex] intValue];
    int updatedValue = previousValue + scoreAdjustmentAmount;
    [_scores replaceObjectAtIndex:baseIndex withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:updatedValue]];
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Have you tried declaring it in your implementation file (`.m`) and initialising it in your `viewDidLoad` method (`self.myMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`)?

Comment: You need to be a little more descriptive

Comment: You can allocate the array in your init method or in viewDidLoad or whatever, or use an "on demand" allocator in a getter method.  Once it's allocated, anyone with a pointer to the containing object can reference that property (if public) and read/write the array.

Comment: In adding code to my question, I realized my key problem was mixing NSMutableArray and NSArray, which was generating the warning that made me think I had something horribly wrong. But I'm thinking I had the general idea right.

Comment: Yep, you can assign an NSMutableArray pointer to an NSArray pointer, but not the other way around.  NSMutableArray is a subclass of NSArray.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are initializing in `viewDidLoad`, However you should do it in `init`.

These both are similar, and perfectly valid.

```
_scores = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@0,@0,@0,@0,nil];
```

or,

```
self.scores=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@0,@0,@0, nil];
```

Your last question... `Then how do I add (NSNumber *)updateValue to, say, the nth value?`
If you `addObject:` it will be added at last. You need to `insertObject:atIndex:` in your required index, and all following objects will shift to next indices.

```
 NSInteger nthValue=12;
[_scores insertObject:updateValue atIndex:nthValue];
```

EDIT:

After your edit,

```
NSInteger previousValue = [[_scores objectAtIndex:baseIndex] integerValue];
NSInteger updatedValue = previousValue + scoreAdjustmentAmount;
[_scores replaceObjectAtIndex:baseIndex withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:updatedValue]];
```

Comment: Thanks. I will move the code to init. I don't want to shift array elements. I just want to update them.

Comment: I get an error "Arithmetic on pointer to NSNumber pointing at the +. Also, you are using _scores instead of scores. Did you mean to do that?

Comment: I updated the text after my Edit:. The key items were that I converted from NSNumber to int, then did the math, then converted to NSNumber before updating the array.

Comment: ok.. i havent compiled and just typed :p  And I would suggest used a wrapper class always like NSInteger, primitive data types should be avoided.

Comment: _scores means you are using property directly. self.scores means you are using accessor. you can use either of them unless you are doing some binding stuff.

Comment: I tried avoiding int at first but couldn't get it to work. I'll try again tomorrow. Zzzzzz time now.

Comment: Sure... I have updated my code..take a nap and do look 2mrw :)

Comment: That works. When I tried NSInteger before, I had an error, that I don't recall. Must have been a typo of some sort, because it's working now.

Comment: I removed the part of your answer about moving from viewDidLoad to init. It does not make sense to clare out the scores when the view is init-ed. Furthermore, it didn't work. So I moved it back to viewDidLoad where it works properly.