# Creating an array in the view controller

Tags: objective-c, arrays, methods

I am still trying to do simple things so I am keeping this example as simple as they come. Here are my files:

h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

 - (NSMutableArray *) createArray;

@property NSMutableArray *myArray;



@end
```

m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self createArray];

    NSLog(@"this is my array: %@",self.myArray);

}

- (NSMutableArray*) createArray {


    self.myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int i = 0; i < (20); i++){
        [self.myArray addObject:[NSNumber
                         numberWithInt:i]];
    }


    return self.myArray;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

@end
```

I am not sure if my logic is wrong, or this is just a small error in what I am typing. Why doesn't this work? Thanks.

Comment: You don't use the return-value of `- (NSMutableArray*) createArray`. This might result in an error.

And maybe you have to add `(strong, nonatomic)` after `@property`

Comment: Time to move to Swift is my advice

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18794929/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSMutableArray property initialization and updating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736586/nsmutablearray-property-initialization-and-updating)

Comment: The code looks fine.  It also runs fine when I run it exactly as you have it here.

Comment: You call createArray for nothing, you need assign it to something like myArray = [self createArray];